# Dynamically cast JsonElement value when mapping Json object

Tags: scala, gson

What I'm trying to achieve here is, in a JSON field which contains more than 1 type of element that I need to use later on but cast in prior stages so there is no need to do so deep in the execution schedule, dynamically map those specific JSON types to the objects so there is no need to do so later.

My actual situation is the following one...

```
 obj.exampleField = json
    .getAsJsonObject(exampleField)
    .entrySet
    .map(entry => entry.getKey -> entry.getValue.getAsString)
    .toMap
```

At the moment everything is a String, but will need to be modified so that `exampleField` starts containing a field which is an `Array` type.

How can I dynamically map those classes within my current `.map` stage? So that a key which contains a String type field is already casted to type resultant of `getAsString` and, in case it's an ArrayType, `getAsJsonArray`.

Or there is no other option rather than avoid the current `.map` stage and move the casting to classes to the last stage in the execution schedule?